# What's the opposite of symploce?

Tags: single-word-requests, rhetorical-devices, poetic-devices

Symploce is two or more sentences / phrases sharing the same beginning and end, but a different middle, while I'm looking for two or more sentences / phrases sharing a middle but different beginnings and ends.

Such as in the question:

> A **is to** B, as C **is to** what?

And

> Roses **are** red, violets **are** blue

Comment: Your examples just display parallelism; there’s no rhetorical force involved.

Comment: @KillingTime - I was the one who flagged this as a dupe because they have the same answer. Haha! :)

Comment: @Malady, the "does this answer..." comments are auto-generated by SE when you vote on a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Mesodiplosis** is according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetition_(rhetorical_device)) "the repetition of a word or phrase at the middle of every clause". It's quite an uncommon term: it's not in Merriam-Webster online dictionary for instance. But you can find it e.g. in Brigham Young U's compilation of rhetorical terms ["Silva Rhetoricae"](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/M/mesodiplosis.htm), which gives an example of the repetition of "not" or "but not" from 2 Corinthians 4:8-9

> We are troubled on every side, yet not distressed; we are perplexed, but not in despair; persecuted, but not forsaken; cast down, but not destroyed.

It contrasts with *anaphora* (repetition at the beginning of a clause) and *epistrophe* (repetition at the end of a clause): the previously-mentioned Wikipedia article on [repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetition_(rhetorical_device)) has a list of other terms.